# Force change label text colour

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I have the following codepen: https://codepen.io/conormdowney/pen/dwmpKQ

Is there a way to force the text of the label at the top of the bars to change colour. If I wanted it to be Red for example. 
I tried the below but it doesnt do anything

```
valueLabel.label.fill = am4core.color("#567");
```

also tried

```
valueLabel.label.text.fill = am4core.color("#567");
```

Comment: `valueLabel.label.fill = am4core.color("#f00");`  turns it red for me. I'm not sure why it isn't working for you, unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Weve actually made a wrapper class that we use, so i cant post that. When set the fill of the label through the wrapper it doesnt update the text colour. Everything else works fine through the wrapper, creating charts and setting colour list. It just wont change the text of the label

Comment: Sounds like there's something up with your wrapper but it's hard to troubleshoot what I can't see. If there's any way to reproduce the issue without sharing any sensitive code, that would really help. If this color change is happening way after the chart has been initialized, try setting the color directly on the bullet object's clones list, e.g. `valueLabel.clones.each((lb) => lb.label.fill = "#f00")` (pardon any syntax errors)

Comment: so the issue was in our css for charts that are used elsewhere in the app. Thanks for the quick resonses